# PircBotX Command issue

Tags: java, irc

I am trying to make a command using the PircBotX Java Framework, and when i am making commands, i have been using this method to listen for the command

```
public void onMessage(MessageEvent event) {
    event.respond("Hello World");
     ...
```

Although, this returns like this, supposing my Nick is Rmarmorstein, and i executed the command..

```
Rmarmorstein: Hello World
```

This is good, although, for fun commands, like a ~poke , it will return this..

```
Rmarmorstein: Poking OtherUser
```

How can i get rid of that Rmarmorstein: in the beginning.. Any Help and suggestions are appreciated, I am using the latest version of the [PircBotX](http://code.google.com/p/pircbotx/) Framework. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
event.getChannel().send().action("pokes OtherUser");
```

Comment: please provide some kind of explanations too while answering questions.

Comment: Basically, PircBotX 2.x revamped how sending works now - PircBotX/Channel/User classes now have send[X]() methods which return objects allowing you to easily send different kind of IRC messages (message/notice/action for channels, message/notice for users, etc.). No need for event.getChannel/getUser() for that kind of things anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Use sendMessage instead of respond:

```
event.getBot().sendMessage(event.getChannel(), "Hello World");
```

Or sendNotice to send, well, a private notice:

```
event.getBot().sendNotice(event.getUser(), "Hello World");
```